# Add List<> To Another List<> by filtering

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have one model class:

```
public class Person 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I adding two list with this:

```
List<Person> people1 = new List<Person> {
    new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "Name1" },
    new Person() { Id = 2, Name = "Name2" },
    new Person() { Id = 3, Name = "Name3" },
};

List<Person> people2 = new List<Person> {
    new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "Name1" },
    new Person() { Id = 4, Name = "Name4" },
    new Person() { Id = 5, Name = "Name5" },
};

people1.AddRange(people2);
```

If `person` in `people2` has the same `id` in `person` in `people1`,  I don't want it added. How can I do that?

Comment: So, you consider two instances of Person to be the same based on Id, only? What should happen if the `Name` property differs? Should the one that's already in people1 be kept or should it be replaced by the other?

Comment: In fact, there is no such possibility because I retrieve this data from the database.
But if you write this possibility as an answer, maybe you can help others.

Comment: Since it doesn't solve your problem, I would prefer someone (preferably the accepted answer) to include it in theirs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *can* use LINQ for this fairly easily but inefficiently:

```cs
people1.AddRange(people2.Where(p2 => !people1.Any(p1 => p1.Id == p2.Id)));
```

Or you could create a set of IDs first:

```cs
HashSet<int> people1Ids = new HashSet<int>(people1.Select(p1 => p1.Id));
people1.AddRange(people2.Where(p2 => !people1Ids.Contains(p2.id));
```

The first approach is obviously simpler, but if your lists get large, it could become slow, because for *every* element in `people2`, it'll look through *every* element in `people1`.

The second approach will be significantly faster *if `people1` is large*. If it's `people2` that's large instead, you won't get much benefit. For example, if `people1` only contains a couple of people, then looking in a hash set for an ID won't be much faster than looking through the list.

You could take an entirely different approach though. If you make your `Person` type implement `IEquatable<Person>` based on ID - or create an `IEqualityComparer<Person>` that does so, and *if* you don't so much need the existing list to be modified, so much as you need "the union of the two lists", and *if* you don't care about the order, and *if* all the entries in each list are unique or you don't mind duplicates being removed, you could just use:

```cs
// Specify the comparer as another argument if you need to.
// You could call ToList on the result if you need a list.
var union = people1.Union(people2);
```

(That's a lot of conditions for that solution, but they may well all be valid.)

Comment: I have doubt whether OP considered the situation from my comment to the question. (What if two `Person`s have same `Id` but different `Name`?)

Comment: +1 for adding 2 solutions, not sure if the second one is performant, but it's easily readable and testable.

Comment: @GlennvanAcker: The second one should perform much better than the first if `people1` is large.

Comment: @Fildor: I've assumed the OP asked the question they wanted to ask.

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair enough, it was just a thought. But it seems that's impossible anyway. So nevermind.

Comment: @MindSwipe: The second will be faster because it won't need to check entries in `people1` to see whether they're unique or not. (I'd forgotten to mention that duplicates are removed by Union, which could matter if either list contains duplicates within itself.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Union__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) operator for this with a custom `IEqualityComparer`. This will create a new list which is a combination of the other 2. Implementing a customer IEqualityComparer gives you control over what constitutes the same record.

```
var allPeople = people1.Union(people2, new PersonComparer());

public class PersonComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
  public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
  {
    // ommited null checks etc
    return x.Id == y.Id;
  }

  public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
  {
    // ommited null checks etc
    return obj.Id.GetHashCode()
  }
}
```

Comment: This will not work. Union uses the Hashcode directly to compare. So just implementing Equals will not do the trick. You will need to add a proper `GetHashCode(Person obj)` implementation for this to work.

Comment: @RobinB correct - I ommited null checks, GetHashCode etc from the above for brevity. Will update for clarity.

Comment: Thanks. I think this could have been a big trap for people seeing this later and just going for `return obj.GetHashCode()` and then asking themselves why their `Equals()` is never executed.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
people1.AddRange(people2.Except(people1));
```

But you first need to Override Equal and GetHashCode in Person class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Person))
            return false;
        Person p = (Person)obj;
        return (p.Id == Id && p.Name == Name);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}|{1}", Id, Name).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Or you can use a a custom equality comparer and then use `Distinct(new DistinctItemComparer())`:

```
public class DistinctItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{

    public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id &&
            x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode() ^
            obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
people1.AddRange(people2.Except(people1, new DistinctItemComparer()));
```

If you just need to distinct based on `Id` you can excluse the `Name` from this two methods.

Based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1046-do-not-overload-operator-equals-on-reference-types?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN), The second approach seems better, as the Microsoft already suggested to *Do not overload operator equals on reference types*.

Answer (score 1):

I think good solution here is to use LINQ. Its quite simple and short code to write :

```
people1.AddRange(people2.Where(x => !people1.Any(y => x.Id == y.Id)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using a `Dictionary` instead?

You can use the `Id` as a `Key` and it won't allow duplicate Keys to exist?

The following code is a way I've used before:

```
var dictionary = people1.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x);

foreach(var person in people2)
{
    if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(item.Id))
    {
        dictionary.Add(item.Id, item);
    }
}
```

There may be a better way of doing it but this has worked for me.

This way when you add an item to the dictionary it won't let you add something with the same `Id`.

Also check out `HashSets` as they do a similar thing.

Comment: The "better way of doing this" is a dictionary[item.ID] = item. Except it prefers the data from the inner-collection in case of duplicates.